# how to read files with special characters in python

Tags: python, file, apache-tika

I have crawled pdf,html,doc files using Apache Tika and stored structured text into text files.These text files contain some unusual special characters,because of these special characters i am unable to read those text files.I have below code snippet to read the files

```
fo = codecs.open('/var/www/testfiles/sample.txt','r','utf-8').read()
```

But,I am getting following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 1291: invalid start byte
```

Please,suggest me how to read my text files.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the 'errors' keyword parameter to something other than the default strict.  You can find a list of possibilities (for Python 3.3) [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs).  The list is enumerated in the "codecs.register()" documentation.

I'd start with the 'replace' option just so you can see what you're dealing with.