# How to read a file with special characters present in its path?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, path

What is done when encountered with special letters in file path, when trying to access it?

To open a file, we need the specific path to the location where it lies. But in cases where the file path itself contains some special characters, like `t`, just after `\`, it shows error:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'tech\tech_part.txt'`.

How to deal with it?

I am writing this in python and the above error results at this line:

```
f = open('tech\tech_part.txt', 'r')
```

Please note that I have already searched over the web and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014535/how-to-read-files-with-special-characters-in-python) and some other (related) queries either not answered (or, done satisfactorily). Any help would be welcomed. If I have missed anything that is already available, please mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a raw string, by putting `r` immediately before the string.

```
f = open(r'tech\tech_part.txt', 'r')
```

This forces Python to not apply the usual rules of backslash escapes, and so it treats `\t` as simply "backslash followed by t", instead of "tab".

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw strings `r'tech\tech_part.txt'` to ignore backslash escapes (except some edge conditions such as a backslash as the last character in the string). But these days, you can use forward slashes with Windows, so just do that.

For all of the string rules, see [`String and Bytes literals`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)